# Avoid some elements in a ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to implement a custom ArrayAdapter for a ListView.

The ArrayList I want to adapt have some positions I want to ignore. (for example when myobject.getValue()>20) how can I indicate that object shouldn't appear in the ListView?

Returning null in the method getView result in a nullPointerException

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out your list before you create the adapter. Go through the original list, checking values, and only add the ones you need to a second list. Then use the second list for your adapter.